# Can I free only a part of a string?

Tags: c, string, free

I am filling up a string of characters and I double its size from time to time.

When I finish, I would like to free unused memory.

```
void fun (char **str, size_t *len) {
  size_t lsi; //last_significant_index
  //filling up the str and reallocating from time to time.
  //*len is storing the total size of allocated memory at this point
  
  // idea #1
  free((*str)[lsi + 1]); 

  // idea #2
  for(size_t i = lsi + 1; i < *len; i++) {
    free(&(*str)[i]);
  }
}
```

None of these ideas seem to work however

### Is it even possible to do it? If so, how?

---

### Details:

I am using this function to reallocate my strings:

```
static void increase_list_size(char **list, size_t *list_len)
{
   size_t new_list_size = (*list_len + 1) * 2; // I am not allocating my list at the declaration, so *list_len initially equals 0.
   char *new_list = malloc(sizeof(char) * new_list_size);
   for (size_t i = 0; i < *list_len; i++)
   {
       new_list[i] = (*list)[i];
   }
   if (list != NULL) // I don't want to free an empty list (it wasn't allocated at the declaration!
   {
       free(*list);
   }
   (*list) = new_list;
   *list_len = new_list_size;
}
```

As you can see, I am allocating two-times more memory every time - that's why I wanted to free unused memory at the end.

I thought there was some kind of a *tricky* way to do it, since I felt that you can only use `free()` to free whole memory block.

Comment: @Kos Its more likely they are using realloc, that is more performant as in many cases it can expand the array in place (assuming the following memory is unused) only copying if needed, still the same principal applies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, you can only `free()` pointers that have been returned by `malloc()`.

You want to use [`realloc()`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) to change the allocated memory size to a smaller (as well as larger) size. The contents of the array will be preserved.

Example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    char *str = malloc(100);
    ...
    str = realloc(str, 50);
    ...
    free(str);
}
```

Remember to check the return value of `realloc()` (as well as the one of `malloc()`) to ensure that the (re)allocation has not failed.

Comment: This answer has it spot on, but I would strongly suggest explaining a little more, it isnt obvious to new programmers that realloc can make an allocation smaller as well as larger.

Answer (score 2):

You can only `free` a pointer that is the result of `malloc` or `realloc`. You can't reduce the size of an allocation by `free`ing at an arbitrary offset from it. But you *can* `realloc` it to a smaller size: `realloc(*str,  lsi)`.

Answer (score 2):

one way is to create a new string and use only space required and copy the content to this one. now you can free the previous one.
I will use this is realloc() is not allowed (sometimes in homework)

the other way is realloc() as others suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard C function `realloc` declared in header `<stdlib.h>`

For example

```
char *s = malloc( 100 );
strcpy( s, "Hello world" );

char *p = realloc( s, strlen( s ) + 1 );

if ( p != NULL ) s = p;
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char *s = malloc( 100 );
    strcpy( s, "Hello world" );

    char *p = realloc( s, strlen( s ) + 1 );

    if ( p != NULL ) s = p; 

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello world
```

Or if you want to write a separate function then it can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void resize( char **s, size_t n )
{
    char *p = realloc( *s, n );

    if ( p != NULL ) *s = p;
}   

int main( void )
{
    char *s = malloc( 100 );
    strcpy( s, "Hello world" );

    resize( &s, strlen( s ) + 1 );

    puts( s );

    free( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Also you can use POSIX function `strdup`